# Quantile-Quantile Plot with Unknown Distribution?

Tags: distributions

[image: N=2762]

**N=2762**

I've been exploring a data set that seems to give rise to this kind of plot rather frequently. Would you say this is one population with a different than normal population? Or are two populations confounding the normal distribution?

It used matplotlib and scipy.stats:

```
      (x,y), (slope, inter, cor) = stats.probplot(data, dist='norm')

      osmf = x.take([0, -1])  # endpoints
      osrf = slope * osmf + inter
      self.ax.plot(x, y, ',', osmf, osrf, '-', **self.kwargs)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the misspelling of "theoretical" in the plot built into the matplotlib and scipy.stats packages?

Comment: Good eye for details =)

Comment: @whuber: That would by my speling of the title `;-)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a variety of different possibilities. For example, a chi-square distribution with degrees of freedom in the range of 30-40 would give rise to such a qq-plot. In R:

```
x <- rchisq(10000, df=35)
qqnorm(x)
qqline(x)
```

looks like this:

[image]

A mixture of two normals with different means doesn't apply though.

```
x <- c(rnorm(10000/2, mean=0), rnorm(10000/2, mean=2))
qqnorm(x)
qqline(x)
```

looks like this:

[image]

Note how the points cross the line, which is a different pattern than the one you observe.

Answer (score 5):

Your dataset clearly is not normal.  (With this much data, any goodness of fit test will tell you that.)  But you can read much more than that from the normal probability plot:

- The generally smooth curvature does not hint at a mixture structure.
- The upper tail is too stretched out (values too high compared to the reference distribution).
- The lower tail is too compressed (values also too high).

This suggests that a mild [Box-Cox transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform) will produce nearly-normal, or at least symmetric, data.   To find it, consider some key values on this plot: the median, found above the x-value of 0, is about 0.90; +2 standard deviations is about 0.99; and -2 standard deviations is about 0.825.  The nonlinearity is apparent from the simple calculations 0.99 - 0.90 = 0.09 whereas 0.90 - 0.825 = 0.075: the rise from the median to the upper tail is greater than the rise from the lower tail to the median.  We can equalize the slopes by trying out some simple re-expressions *of these three values only.*  For example, taking the reciprocals of the three key data values (Box-Cox power of -1) gives

```
1/0.825 = 1.21
1/0.90  = 1.11; 1.21 - 1.11 = 0.10 (new slope is 0.050 per SD)
1/0.99  = 1.01; 1.11 - 1.01 = 0.10 (0.050 per SD)
```

Because the slopes *of the re-expressed values* are now equal, we know the plot of *reciprocals* of the data will be approximately linear between -2 and +2 SDs.  As a check, let's pick more points further out into the tails and see what the reciprocal does to them.  I estimate that the value in the plot at -3 SD from the mean is around 0.79 and the value +3 SD from the mean is 1.05.  The two slopes in question equal 0.053 and 0.052 per SD: close enough to each other *and* to the slopes found between -2 and +2 SD.

My estimates--based on the plot as shown on a monitor--are crude, so you will want to repeat these (simple, quick) calculations with the actual data.  Nevertheless, there is considerable evidence that your data when suitably re-expressed with a simple transformation will be close to normally distributed.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to take a look at the   [Anderson-Darling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test#Test_for_Normality) test for normality which empirically tests whether or not your data comes from a given distribution. @chl recommends looking at the `scipy` toolkit, specifically `anderson()` in `morestats.py` for an implementation.

Comment: It's a little nitpicky but the CLT doesn't tell us that the 'sample' itself will be normally distributed.

Comment: @Chase In python, the AD test for normal, exponential, or Gumbel dist. is available in the [scipy](http://www.scipy.org/) toolkit (see `anderson()` in `morestats.py`).

Comment: @Dason - nice catch and good point. I modified my answer to more accurately reflect that subtlety. @chl - thanks for the reference. I don't have any experience with python, I'm still trying to grok R in my spare time!

Comment: @Chase where is the modification you promised to @Dason?  Your answer still asserts that all "samples" of n >= 30 will be "normal," which is plainly wrong.  That's no "nitpick": it's fundamental.

Comment: @whuber - Feel free to modify my answer as you see fit, you almost certainly have more expertise in formal statistics than I do. My answer above states that a sampled population will be "approximately" normal as `n` increases with `n == 30` as the generally accepted rule of thumb for minimum `n`. That language comes directly out of my stats 101 text book and class notes. I understand "approximately" is a bit of a vague term though unfortunately I don't have the experience or expertise to offer any further insight into defining "approximately".

Comment: @Chase The potential for confusion here is that your stats textbook is referring to the distribution of the *sample mean,* not the sample data.  As you draw more and more data from *any* non-normal distribution, it will more and more clearly show itself to be non-normal! -- but, under mild assumptions, the *means* of many independent such samples will be almost normally distributed.

Comment: It's not the *sample* itself that starts to resemble a normal distribution, but the distribution of certain *statistics* (like the mean) that will be approximately normally distributed.

Comment: @whuber Got it, I understand the difference now - thanks for the clarification. If that's the case, then the CLT doesn't seem terribly applicable after all and I'm just babbling on confirming my idiocy in front of all of the interwebs...right?

Comment: @Wolfgang Very nicely put!  In two lines you said what I could not express in 10.  @Chase Look at it this way: for the price of writing a few comments online and suffering the criticism of fools like me you have today learned something important that was somehow overlooked in an entire semester's course.  That's an efficient way to learn (and the price is right, too).  You will come across as quite knowledgeable once you fix that initial response :-).

Comment: @whuber - you are certainly on track with the price being right! I have thick skin and appreciate the time and thoughtful answers that others on this site provide. I hope that I can provide some useful knowledge back to this site as well. I'm quite confident my instructors did a very sufficient job at teaching these basic concepts and the issue is my inability to *apply* that information in an appropriate context. I was a little over zealous here and grasping at straws trying to fit a concept I vaguely understood to a question. As they say, when all you've got is a hammer...